# How does serving static files from another server is done?

Tags: python, http, server

I'am just starting out in web development through python and flask, and I was trying to use some static files ( a static index.html file), i've searched on plenty of websites how to do it, And most answers worked .

The problem I'am having is that I couldn't understand how does serving static files from another server like apache or nginx works .

I'am not looking for sepecific explanation on how to set it up, since there  tons of tutorials online, I just need someone to explain how all that stuff works in a simple beginner friendly way .

**Few Questions :**

- How do servers generally serve static files ?
- What's static file serving really means ?
- How can other servers serve static file for an app on a different
  server ?
- Why can't I just include them using some plain HTML like an old
  simple website ?

Enlighten me please .